# Next.js Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token, then ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk app/layout failed

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a pretty minimal app at the moment implementing redux (following the official redux docs) and implementing some persistence of the data to local storage. I am facing a very stressful problem where i get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at layout.js:93:29)
```

in my console. If i leave the error there, the app completely crashed and i get:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk app/layout failed. (timeout: http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/app/layout.js))
```

The thing is that the errors are kind of random. It usually occurs (but not always) in a first page load after running `npx next dev`

If i reload the page, everything starts working normally until i restart the server. Then the error appears again. I having a hard time trying to debug, specially because it can happen that i run `npx next dev` 4 ou 5 times and get no error, then it starts appearing again for a random number of server restarts. In any case, always, i can get rid of the error reloading the page.

Current code:

layout.tsx

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import "./globals.css";
import StoreProvider from "./StoreProvider";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "App",
  description: "App Description",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <StoreProvider>{children}</StoreProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

StoreProvider.tsx

```
"use client";

import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { makeStore, AppStore } from "../redux/store";
import { updateUser } from "@/redux/user/userSlice";

export default function StoreProvider({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore>();

  if (!storeRef.current) {
    // Create the store instance the first time this renders
    storeRef.current = makeStore();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (storeRef.current !== undefined) {
      storeRef.current.dispatch(
        updateUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")!))
      );
    }
  }, []);

  return <Provider store={storeRef.current}>{children}</Provider>;
}
```

userSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

interface userInterface {
    value: {
        id: string | number,
        email: string,
        username: string | null,
        avatar?: string | null,
        name?: string,
        lastname: string,
        isAdmin?: string | boolean

    } | null
}

const initialState: userInterface = {
    value: null
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateUser: (state, action) => {
            state.value = action.payload
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(state.value))
        },
        clearUser: (state) => {
            state.value = null
            localStorage.removeItem('user')
        }
    }
})

export const userReducer = userSlice.reducer
export const { updateUser, clearUser } = userSlice.actions
```

store.ts

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {userReducer} from "./user/userSlice"

export const makeStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: {user: userReducer}
  })
}

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>
export type RootState = ReturnType<AppStore['getState']>
export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch']
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but in Chrome development only. If I run the app in Chrome as production, no error, and Edge and Firefox do not present this issue in either case. In Chrome dev only, the error isn't coming from app/layout.js. It's coming from .next/static/chunks/app/layout.js. It seems that there's a tailwindcss conflict. If I comment out tailwindcss: {} in postcss.config.js, there's no issue. Are you also using tailwind?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Error happens in layout.js, it says Invalid or unexpected token. My environment is next.js, typescript, material-tailwind. when I comment out <ThemeProvider> component that is covered <html> for using material-tailwind, error doesn't happen.