Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at layout.js:61:29)
This error appears when the application starts, but the browser continues running the application normally:
Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at layout.js:61:29)
This error appears immediately after starting the application in the browser in layout.js on line 61, but my code is in a layout file with a .tsx extension and not .js, this code is generated by the browser using my source code.
And after some time of development the application crashes and a blank screen is displayed, but some hydration errors only appear in the console, here they are:
Uncaught ChunkLoadError
    at __webpack_require__.f.j (webpack.js?v=1720532574158:852:29)
    at webpack.js?v=1720532574158:155:40
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.e (webpack.js?v=1720532574158:154:67)
    at fn.e (webpack.js?v=1720532574158:391:50)
    at loadChunk (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:244:30)
    at preloadModule (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:170:22)
    at resolveModule (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1813:17)
    at processFullRow (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1902:9)
    at processBinaryChunk (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2072:7)
__webpack_require__.f.j @ webpack.js?v=1720532574158:852
(anônimo) @ webpack.js?v=1720532574158:155
__webpack_require__.e @ webpack.js?v=1720532574158:154
fn.e @ webpack.js?v=1720532574158:391
loadChunk @ react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:244
preloadModule @ react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:170
resolveModule @ react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1813
processFullRow @ react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1902
processBinaryChunk @ react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2072
progress @ react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2153
Mostrar mais 6 frames
Mostrar menos
app-index.js:33 Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>.
window.console.error @ app-index.js:33
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js:63
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:94
error @ react-dom.development.js:68
errorHydratingContainer @ react-dom.development.js:36301
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:24593
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24542
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:256
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:225
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:534
Mostrar mais 10 frames
Mostrar menos
react-dom.development.js:9126 Uncaught ChunkLoadError
    at __webpack_require__.f.j (webpack.js?v=1720532574158:852:29)
    at webpack.js?v=1720532574158:155:40
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.e (webpack.js?v=1720532574158:154:67)
    at fn.e (webpack.js?v=1720532574158:391:50)
    at loadChunk (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:244:30)
    at preloadModule (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:170:22)
    at resolveModule (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1813:17)
    at processFullRow (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1902:9)
    at processBinaryChunk (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2072:7)
__webpack_require__.f.j @ webpack.js?v=1720532574158:852
(anônimo) @ webpack.js?v=1720532574158:155
__webpack_require__.e @ webpack.js?v=1720532574158:154
fn.e @ webpack.js?v=1720532574158:391
loadChunk @ react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:244
preloadModule @ react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:170
resolveModule @ react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1813
processFullRow @ react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1902
processBinaryChunk @ react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2072
progress @ react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2153
Mostrar mais 6 frames
Mostrar menos
app-index.js:33 The above error occurred in the <ServerRoot> component:

    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:112:27)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:117:11)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
window.console.error @ app-index.js:33
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js:63
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:15295
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:15321
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:8696
commitCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:8743
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21461
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:22912
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26226
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26077
commitRootWhenReady @ react-dom.development.js:24749
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:24714
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24559
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:256
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:225
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:534
Mostrar mais 16 frames
Mostrar menos
react-dom.development.js:16571 Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
    at updateHostRoot (react-dom.development.js:16571:57)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:18486:14)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:26927:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:25748:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:25464:5)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:25419:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:24597:20)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24542:26)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:256:34)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:225:14)
updateHostRoot @ react-dom.development.js:16571
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:18486
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:26927
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:25748
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:25464
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:25419
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:24597
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24542
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:256
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:225
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:534
Mostrar mais 11 frames
Mostrar menos
react-dom.development.js:26325 Uncaught ChunkLoadError
    at __webpack_require__.f.j (webpack.js?v=1720532574158:852:29)
    at webpack.js?v=1720532574158:155:40
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.e (webpack.js?v=1720532574158:154:67)
    at fn.e (webpack.js?v=1720532574158:391:50)
    at loadChunk (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:244:30)
    at preloadModule (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:170:22)
    at resolveModule (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1813:17)
    at processFullRow (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1902:9)
    at processBinaryChunk (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2072:7)

I've tried searching in several sources, but I didn't find the solution, please help me!I've tried searching in several sources, but I didn't find the solution, please help me!

I already tried to configure webbpack in my next.config.mjs file, but I was successful, I really need help!

related to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77788615/next-js-uncaught-syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token-then-chunkloaderror
