Why am I getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError" that leads to ChunkLoadError's and hydration error in next.js?
Hello, I have a next.js project that I just started. When I run npm run dev on Chrome, I get the following error in the Chrome console:
layout.js:160 Uncaught 
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at layout.js:160:29)

Additionally, my one onClick event and all the Link components stop working. After a minute or so, the page crashes with a Unhandled Runtime Error, and the console prints out a couple more errors. Those errors are a couple of Uncaught ChunkLoadError and the following:
Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>.

The error happens on maybe 3 out of 5 times when I start the dev server too. No errors in the node terminal, only on the browser.

Does anyone know what could be a cause for this problem and if it is something that I need to fix before continuing my project? Any tips on how I can resolve my problem?
My code so far (without the commented components):
layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Montserrat } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar/Navbar'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer/Footer'

// const montserrat = Montserrat({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

Navbar.tsx
import Link from 'next/link'
import Menu from '@/components/Menu/Menu'

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className='h-20 pt-1 px-4 md:px-8 lg:px-16 xl:px-32 2xl:px-64 relative'>
      <div className='flex justify-between items-center'>
        <Link href='/'>TRAVEL PLANNER</Link>
        {/* <Menu /> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar

Footer.tsx
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <a href='https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/hiking' title='hiking icons'>
        Hiking icons created by Freepik - Flaticon
      </a>
      <a
        href='https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/camping'
        title='camping icons'
      >
        Camping icons created by Freepik - Flaticon
      </a>
      <a
        href='https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/up-and-down'
        title='up and down icons'
      >
        Up and down icons created by Freepik - Flaticon
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Footer

dependencies:
{
  "name": "travel-planner-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^14.2.8",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^6.2.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "3.3.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

Please let me know if I need to clarify on anything or if I am mistaken about something. I am still fairly new with Next.js 14 and server components too.
My attempts to resolve that did not work:
I looked over my code to make sure there weren't any syntax errors, though I could have missed something.
I tried comparing the html on the server side against the html on the client side by looking at the html in the Network tab and the Elements tab of the Chrome Dev tool. I couldn't see any difference in the body of the html.
I tried deleting the .next folder and clearing my node modules for a fresh restart, which worked for a bit, but the error returned after a couple of starts. I also tried clearing the cache on Chrome.
Finally, I tried narrowing down the root of the error by commenting out elements and components (since I have very few from just starting it). It seems that the error only shows up when I have any Link components or when my onClick event is present. Leaving any one of them uncommented yields the error. I checked out the documentation for the Link component on next.js website, but I could not find something I was doing incorrectly. Anchor tags don't create the error.
I also checked the following stackoverflow question and Next.js documentation, but couldn't find a permanent solution or an explanation through them (or maybe the solution was in the doc and I did not understand:
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77788615/next-js-uncaught-syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token-then-chunkloaderror

You forgot to surround {children} in Navbar by main div. Here is the right code:
<main>{children}</main>

. Add this in your layout.js and I'm sure it wil work.

I gave that a try, but I still have the error on some occasions of starting the next.js dev server

Why don't you debug it  by running npm run build ?

It didn't shownany problems, but! I haven't seen the error during dev since I've ran 'npm run build'.    Is there a reason why?
